# TypeError: 'TensorShape' object is not callable

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow programming , i was digging up some functions and got this error in the snippet :

```
**with** **tf.Session()** as sess_1:
c = tf.constant(5)
d = tf.constant(6)
e = c + d
print(sess_1.run(e))
print(sess_1.run(e.shape()))
```

Error found :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ashu/PycharmProjects/untitled/Bored.py", line 15, in 
    print(sess_1.run(e.shape()))
TypeError: 'TensorShape' object is not callable

I didn't found it here so can anyone please clarify this silly doubt as i am new learner.Sorry for any typing mistake !

I have a one more doubt , when i uses simply eval() function it doesn't print anything in pycharm , i had to use it along with print() method. So my doubt is when print() method is used it doesn't print the dtype of the tensor , it simply print the tensor or python object value in pycharm.(Why i am not getting the output in the format like : array([1. , 1.,] , dtype=float32))Is it the Pycharm way to print the tensor in new version or is it something i am doing wrong ? So excited to know the thing behind this , please help and pardon if i am wrong at any place.

Answer (score 5):

One confusing aspect of tensorflow for beginners is there are two types of shape: *dynamic shape*, given by `tf.shape(x)`, and *static shape*, given by `x.shape` (assuming `x` is a tensor). While they represent the same concept, they are used very differently.

Static shape is the shape of a tensor known at run time. Its a data type in its own right, but it can be converted to a list using `as_list()`.

```
x = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 3, 4))
static_shape = x.shape
shape_list = x.shape.as_list()
print(shape_list)  # [None, 3, 4]

y = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1)
print(y.shape.as_list())  # [None, 4]
```

During operations, tensorflow tracks static shapes as best it can. In the above example, y's shape was calculated based on the partially known shape of `x`'s. Note we haven't even created a session, but the static shape is still known.

Since the batch size is not known, you can't use the static first entry in calculations.

```
z = tf.reduce_sum(x) / tf.cast(x.shape.as_list()[0], tf.float32)  # ERROR
```

(we could have divided by `x.shape.as_list()[1]`, since that dimension is known at run-time - but that wouldn't demonstrate anything here)

If we need to use a value which is not known statically - i.e. at graph construction time - we can use the *dynamic shape* of `x`. The dynamic shape is a tensor - like other tensors in tensorflow - which is evaluated using a session.

```
z = tf.reduce_sum(x) / tf.cast(tf.shape(x)[0], tf.float32)  # all good!
```

You can't call `as_list` on the dynamic shape, nor can you inspect its values without going through a session evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run), you can only call a session's `run` method with tensors, operations, or lists of tensors/operations. Your last line of code calls `run` with the result of `e.shape()`, which has type `TensorShape`. The session can't execute a `TensorShape` argument, so you're getting an error.

When you call `print` with a tensor, the system prints the tensor's content. If you want to print the tensor's type, use code like `print(type(tensor))`.